# Facing high cost of Dynamodb

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-data, amazon-dynamodb

We are using AWS dynamodb as database server and java application interacts with

this. As Mentioned over aws server pricing is too low for Free Tier account:

https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/pricing/.

But we are getting bill in thousands of dollar.

Is anything is missing or we need to change some configuration over aws?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For AWS Billing issue, you can contact AWS Support team.

You can reach out here https://console.aws.amazon.com/support for creating a case.
Choose Regarding as Account and Billing Support, service as Billing, category as Charge Inquiry.

They will display some list of related questions below category which will be useful for you. After creating a case, AWS Support team will reach out through Phone or Web within 24 hours.

If you are facing technical issues regarding your use case, select as Technical support to reach out for help.